# how to provide notification with PHP

Tags: php, html

please explanation of how to provide notification when I successfully enter data into a form that is stored in the database?

[image: the picture below is an example]
[image]

the picture above is an example notivikasi when the form is empty, I ask how to make a successful notivikasi when the form is filled in with data?

```html
    if (isset($_POST['btnsimpan'])) {
      $nama_kat     = $_POST['nama_kat'];
      $pesanError   = array();

      if (trim($nama_kat)=="") {
        $pesanError[] = "<b>Kategori</b> masih Kosong cuy,...!!";
      }

      $cekSql="SELECT * FROM kategori WHERE nama_kat='$nama_kat'";
      $cekQry=mysql_query($cekSql) or die ("Eror Query".mysql_error()); 
      if(mysql_num_rows($cekQry)>=1){
        $pesanError[] = "Sorry bos Kategori <b> $nama_kat </b> sudah ada, ganti dengan yang lain ya,..!!";
  }

      if ($pesanError){
        echo "<div class='msgError'>";
        foreach ($pesanError as $indeks=>$pesan_tampil) { 
        echo "$pesan_tampil<br>";
      } 
      echo "</div> <br>";
    }
    else {
      $mySql = "INSERT INTO kategori (nama_kat) VALUES ('$nama_kat')";
      $myQry = mysql_query($mySql) or die ("gagal".mysql_error());
    }
  }
   
$dtnama_kat = isset($POST['nama_kat']) ? $_POST['nama_kat'] : '';

?>
    <div class="judul"><h2>Tambah Data Kategori</h2></div>
    <div class="area_main">
      <form method="POST" action="<?php #echo "$aksi?mod=kat&aksi=tb_dt"; ?>" >
        <table class="form">
        <tr>
            <td>Nama Kategori</td>
            <td>:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="nama_kat" id="nama_kat" value="<?php echo $dtnama_kat; ?>" size="41px" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="btnsimpan" class="button" value="Simpan"> </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
   </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: where you want to provide the notification??

Comment: i want to give in class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The section of the provided code that adds the error message is:

```
  if ($pesanError){
    echo "<div class='msgError'>";
    foreach ($pesanError as $indeks=>$pesan_tampil) { 
    echo "$pesan_tampil<br>";
  } 
  echo "</div> <br>";
```

To add a success message, `echo` your message in the `else` section that actually updates the database:

```
else {
  $mySql = "INSERT INTO kategori (nama_kat) VALUES ('$nama_kat')";
  $myQry = mysql_query($mySql) or die ("gagal".mysql_error());

  echo '<div class="msgSuccess">YOUR MESSAGE HERE</div>';

}
```

This will output a `<div>` with the CSS class `msgSuccess` just before the `<div class="judul"><h2>Tambah Data Kategori</h2></div>` content of your HTML document. If you want the message in another location, store it in a variable and echo that variable in the proper location in the HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

you can  can set in GET method with variable. and on form you have to retrieve it using $_GET.

Comment: please give an example?

Comment: use below link:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/showphp.asp?filename=demo_form_validation_complete